# WinForm Combobox - incorrect SelectedValue at Form load

Tags: winforms, linq-to-sql, data-binding, combobox, lookup

My windows Form  contains 1 combobox bound to Categories bindingsource, and 1 datagrid bound to Products binding source. When I load the form the combobox shows the first value in the categories table and not the selected value in the Products table, and when I change position in the Products bindingsource I can get the right selectedValue in the combobox (it displays correct values).  So My problem is in the first load of combobox items.

My Combo properties:

data source     =  categorybindingsource

display Member  =  CategoryName

Value Member    =  CategoryID

Selected Value  =  productBindingSource – CategoryID

And here is my code:

```
NorthwindDataContext dc;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dc = new NorthwindDataContext();
    productBindingSource.DataSource = dc.Products;

    this.categoryIDComboBox.DataSource = dc.Categories;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to invert the order of initialization of combobox and datagrid

```
NorthwindDataContext dc; 
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    dc = new NorthwindDataContext(); 
    this.categoryIDComboBox.DataSource = dc.Categories; 
    productBindingSource.DataSource = dc.Products; 
}
```

Comment: That's right, initialization of Combo should be before datagrid, thank you Steve.